# Is melamine soluble in methanol? if it is then what is the solubility of it ? In grams/mL?

Tags: solubility

I am trying to dissolve 100 mg of melamine in 35 mL of methanol. But after stirring and heating the solution for more than two hours I couldn't get any clear solution. Where have I gone wrong? I couldn't find the solubility of melamine in methanol. Kindly help

Answer (score 2):

Melamine is described as being "slightly soluble in water and alcohol" [data here](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/melamine#section=Solubility).
The figure for Ethanol is quoted as 0.6g per litre [here](https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/15978/4/10).

While I cannot find a figure for methanol, these data lead me to think that you will need more methanol to dissolve 100mg. Ethylene glycol is a better [choice](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_solvent_of_melamine2)